# Python Impyla fails after Kerberos install

Tags: python-2.7, kerberos, anaconda, impala

I'm on a W7 machine, where I use Python (Anaconda distribution) to connect to Impala in our Hadoop cluster using the Impyla package.
My company has recently added Kerberos and that ended up breaking what I had in place.

**before Kerberos:**

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
conn = connect( host='localhost', port=21050)
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('SHOW TABLES')
cur.fetchall()
```

**after Kerberos**

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
conn = connect( host='localhost', port=21050, use_kerberos=True,
               kerberos_service_name='impala/myservername')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-068c7348729f>", line 2, in <module>
    kerberos_service_name='impala/myservername')

  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\impala\dbapi\__init__.py", line 47, in connect
    ldap_password, use_kerberos, kerberos_service_name)

  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\impala\_rpc\hiveserver2.py", line 193, in connect_to_impala
    use_kerberos, kerberos_service_name)

  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\impala\_rpc\hiveserver2.py", line 166, in _get_transport
    import sasl

ImportError: No module named sasl
```

I tried installing sasl from CMD:

```
>easy_install sasl
Searching for sasl
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/sasl/
Best match: sasl 0.1.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/sasl/sasl-0.1.3.tar.gz#md5
=6db4ca3d4fb699cf126a6e6f2f516d8f
Processing sasl-0.1.3.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\x\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-zfqesn\sasl-0.1.3\setup
.cfg
Running sasl-0.1.3\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\x\appdata\loc
al\temp\easy_install-zfqesn\sasl-0.1.3\egg-dist-tmp-cl0non
sasl/saslwrapper.cpp:21:23: fatal error: sasl/sasl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Users\\x\\AppData\\Loc
al\\Continuum\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you are running Windows. Are you running cygwin or some other python?

Have you tried:

1. If using Cygwin, have you tried installing libsasl2-devel  ?
2. installing python-sasl from the GIT repository as Cloudera seems to do as part of their [jenkins environment](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/blob/86e1a9f916785ccc77700de4327ecf77e4820fbd/jenkins/run-dbapi.sh#L90)?

   pip install git+https://github.com/laserson/python-sasl.git@cython

Should do the magic.

By the way, the code you are using has been deprecated (as per the current GitHub master).

Use

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
conn = connect( host='localhost', port=21050, auth_mechanism='GSSAPI',
               kerberos_service_name='impala')
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to build `sasl` from source on Windows, given that you recommend it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue but i fixed it by installing the right version of required libraries.

Install below python libraries using `pip`:

```
six==1.12.0
bit_array==0.1.0
thrift==0.9.3
thrift_sasl==0.2.1
sasl==0.2.1
impyla==0.13.8
```

Below code is working with `python` version `2.7` and `3.4`.

```
import ssl
from impala.dbapi import connect
import os
os.system("kinit")
conn = connect(host='hostname.io',
              port=21050,
              use_ssl=True,
              database='default',
              user='urusername',
              kerberos_service_name='impala',
              auth_mechanism = 'GSSAPI')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SHOW DATABASES;')
result=cur.fetchall()
for data in result:
    print (data)
```